# Why would sample probability more than zero equal sample probability more than half?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

In calculating probabilities for Roulette, my text book asks me to calculate the probability of winning after 1,000 bets.

Where spending \$1 has a $\frac{1}{38}$ probability of winning \$35 and a $\frac{37}{38}$ probability of loosing \$1.

The answer uses the formula

$P(S>0)=P(S>0.5)$ $\approx$ 1-$\phi$ $(\frac{.5+0.526 n}{\sqrt(33.21 n)} ) $

I understand from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3847693/when-calculating-probability-in-roulette-why-dont-we-add-the-probabilities-of-w) that the mean works out to be -0.0596 and the variance is 33.21

Why is S>0.5 the same as S>0?

Where does the 0.5 come from?

Why is 0.5 added to the mean?

Comment: minor typo : ...has a $\frac{1}{38}$ probability of winning $35...

Comment: Since you can only win or lose an integer number of dollars, $P(S>0)=P(S≥1)=P(S>.5)$.  The reason you include the $.5$ is because of the so-called [continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction) that you need when you approximate a discrete distribution by a continuous one.

Comment: Should say, the mean for a single game is not $.596$   It's $\frac 1{38}\times 35-\frac {37}{38}\times 1=-.0526$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. What does S stand for here? Why $P(S$ $\ge$ 1) ?

Comment: The $S$ is from your post.  I assume you meant for $S$ to denote the amount of winnings.  The problem asks, then, for the probability that $S>0$.

Comment: Thankyou @lulu, I have copied from the textbook. I wondered if it was S for Sample. Winnings makes sense. In your comment above why  P(S≥1)=P(S>0.5) ? For example why would P(2) match P(1) ?

Comment: Nobody said $P(2)=P(1)$.  Since you can only win an integer number of dollars, If I tell you you got more than fifty cents, you know you must have won at least $\$1$.